# Hook EN_CHANGE in dialog for subclassing CEDIT

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, dialog, cedit

I have my own subclassed class for CEDIT as following:

```
class MyEdit : public CEdit....
```

I subclassed it in `DoDataExchange` procedure by `DDX_control`
I hook in this subclassed class `ON_CHAR` and `ON_CHANGE` `(MyEdit::OnChar, MyEdit::OnChange).`

I need hook `ON_CHANGE` event also in parent dialog, but with subclassing class it does not work.

Is here some way how manually send from  `MyEdit::OnChange` message to dialog?

Comment: The obvious solution to sending a message to a parent is to use `SendMessage`. If there is a reason why you cannot use that you need to include that into your question.

Answer (score -1):

I have just solved it. I have solved missing `EN:CHANGE` by using `EN_UPDATE` event. `EN_UPDATE` is posting despite sublclassing `CEdit`...

Comment: That may (appear to) solve your immediate issue, but isn't an answer to the question s being asked. `EN_CHANGE` and `EN_UPDATE` are notifications sent in response to different events. They cannot be used interchangeably, which this proposed answer seems to suggest.

Comment: Yes, I solved my problem. Partly.. If somebody knows, how to solve it comletely, how to use both events in Control procedure and in dialog procedure also, I like to learn.

Comment: I left a suggestion in a comment to the question, and asked whether you can or cannot use that. It would help if you responded to that question.

Comment: Thanks, I have not seen it. It means,  from CEdit procedure send the message explicitly to parent window?